# Filling text with flag colors

Tags: adobe-illustrator

So, I've tried creating a flag on the artboard (essentially three rectangles of different color, and one star), and then type text on top of it.  I've tried different ways using Pathfinder to minus front, so that I'm left with just text filled with the flag colors, but can't seem to pull it off.  The text is converted to shape/outline, and the shapes underneath were outlined stroke.

Alternatively, I've tried the "Draw Inside" and "Place" an image of the flag, which 'kind of' works, but not really because it becomes badly distorted.

Is there another method, or just a better way of doing something like this?

Edit: just wanted to make sure I described the look I'm going for... basically to look like each letter was cut right out from a flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Group the flag shapes
- Make a mask with a black frame and a white text

[image: FLAG]

- Select both groups and use the **Transparency Panel** to make a **Clipping Mask**

[image: MASK]

- Invert the mask to obtain the opposite

[image: inverted mask]

- Edit the mask to change the text
- Edit the artboard to change the flag colors

[image]

Comment: That definitely works!  Thank you so much... one follow up, how would I get a black stroke to still appear outlining the text... since it's on white and some of the flag is white?  Thank you again for your quick help!

Comment: Also it seems like after I apply the mask... I can only move the group around, but not edit live text like the last part of your walkthrough.  I must just be missing something there

Comment: To change the text you must click the mask thumbnail at the Transparency Panel to get into the mask edit mode.

Comment: Ahh, yes I see that now... though changing it to a black stroke still appears white on the white background, if that makes sense?

Comment: @RichF To get an outline, make a copy of the text, paste in place, then set a stroke and no fill.

Comment: Thanks so much again, worked perfectly (even if I don't really understand clipping masks still)